# Angular Universal TTFB is very slow

Tags: angular, angular-universal, angular-devkit

When I run my application with angular universal, I am seeing huge difference in TTFB. ssr is taking more time than normal angular command. How to improve TTFB with angular universal server side rendering?

```
npm run serve:ssr
```

[image]

**Performance tab:**
[image]

```
ng serve
```

[image]

Looked into many sites but didn't found any relevant solution on internet till yet.

Comment: open dev tools' `Performance` tab, record loading and see what it shows.

Comment: @c69 Added screenshot of performance tab.

Comment: this is very annoying, they tell you that SSR and Angular Universal is the solution, and when you try them and experience the slowness you can't find any resources to help

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and I fixed it by removing all `setTimeout` and `setInterval`

If you need to use timeouts you can use this function instead of the regular `setTimeout`

```js
export function setTimeout$(cb: () => void, timer: number) {
  of(true).pipe(debounceTime(timer), first()).subscribe(cb);
}
```

Comment: `debounceTime()` is not doing the right job, but `delay()` works fine

Comment: I have removed the setTImeout function but site still loading at same time.. if i increase the settimeout time to 10 sec.. page load after 10 sec... pls help

Comment: @pina0_M4n please advice

Comment: @VenkaTeshuser5397700 You missed one. Check the npm packages you are loading, check the services imported. Some other library has a timeout

Comment: @Pian0_M4n i did the search using visual studio code. i didn't see any settimeout function inside the library...

Comment: maybe intervals?

Comment: okay @Pian0_M4n but i didn't see any setTimeout, setInterval, timeout in find / search visual studio code

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you have a setTimeout or an http call that takes too much time to finish and angular universal does not serve the webpage until all the calls are finished.

I recommend you that if the timeout or http call is not essential to render the webpage, avoid the call on the server side.

Comment: I have the same problem, but what if i have a home page that have multiple requests, and also the request would take for example 4 seconds to finish (on slow 3G), but why the loading of the website is taking 14 seconds