# angular universal, NestJs TTFB Takes more that 5 Seconds to load

Tags: angular, nestjs, angular-universal

Please assist i have a angular 8 nestJs application, i am using angular universal `@nestjs/ng-universal` to render both applications as one. I then notice a more than 5 second delay/waiting(TTFB). When i `ng serve` the angular part is quick(about 3ms). Saw the following [Angular Universal TTFB is very slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57367354/angular-universal-ttfb-is-very-slow) but doesnt help me much. looking at the browser logs i see the following below:

```
[Violation] 'load' handler took 347ms
```

Can i add something to Nest to reduce TTFB, I didn't add any setTimeout to the code so i don't understand why it takes 5sec not less. my main.ts is as follows :

```
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(ApplicationModule);
  app.setGlobalPrefix('api');

  const options = new DocumentBuilder()
    .setTitle('Cars API V1')
    .setDescription('Cars API')
    .setVersion('1.0')
    .addBearerAuth()
    .build();

  const document = SwaggerModule.createDocument(app, options);
  SwaggerModule.setup('swagger', app, document);

  await app.listen(4200);
}
bootstrap();
```

My nestJS app module is as follows:

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    SharedModule,
    HttpModule,
    AngularUniversalModule.forRoot({
      cache: false,
      viewsPath: BROWSER_DIR,
      bundle: require('../server/main')
    }),
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      isGlobal: true
    }),
  ],
  controllers: [AppController,],
  providers: [AppService]
})
export class ApplicationModule {}
```

Comment: are you making any http calls at all for data by default throughout your application? if yes, a general solution would be to use a HTTP interceptor to delay/cancel all calls until you're running in the browser.